# selecting unique random values from different rows

Tags: sql, teradata

I have entries like:

```
first_col,   second_col
  'john' ,   'chips'
  'john' ,   'candy bars'
  'luke' ,   'pop corn'
```

so that some values for first_col can have (but don't need to) several values in second_col (and the multiplicity is not constant). I would like to retrieve a unique value of second_col associated with first_col, and it should be selected randomly from the existing possibilities. For example, for 'John' I'd randomly pick among 'chips' and 'candy bars'.

I'm using Teradata, if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: as you explain the mater, picking any random row is enough to complain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunaly, I don't have Teradata at home, but try this decision (on oracle). Simply, I add random value to each row and sort by it, and get first row for each group

```
SELECT first_col,
  MAX(second_col) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY num) as rand_second_col 
  FROM 
(SELECT first_col, second_col,dbms_random.value() as num
  FROM table)  tmp
  GROUP BY first_col
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
SELECT [col1],min([col2]) as col2,NEWID()
  FROM [testtable] group by [col1] order by NEWID()
```

i have made a table with below data and it works

```
col1    col2
john    chips
john    candy bars
luke    pop corn
john    ice
```

and output is

```
col1    col2              (No column name)
luke    pop corn    E8CCD6A2-27A8-4728-B16F-2B1EFEAFA8A1
john    candy bars  D135E1E0-5193-41F1-A5F9-B55F68CF6156
```

Answer (score -1):

teradata, unlike most rdbms, has a built in sampling function.

```
select * from tablename
sample 10;
```

I don't know  what `sample 10` does behind the scenes. Anecdotally, the data is different every time and a lot of distinct values are returned.

Comment: I don't think that does what I want. I want ALL the values for first_column, and for those which have multiplicity in second_column, I want a random one.

Comment: you're looking for a correlated subquery; `select top 1 ... order by rand()`. Sorry, ignore my answer.